# Php preg_replace_callback no work me

Tags: php, str-replace, preg-replace-callback

I try replace characters from string and put others , for this use preg_replace_callback function , the problem is this function change order of original text and show differents results

**For example if the string it´s :**

Hello everybody [1-2-3] this it´s one test [4-5-6-7-8] **--- > ORIGINAL TEXT**

**The script search the [ ] and separate this content with [ ] from the other text , but show me as i put here :**

1-2-3 4-5-6-7-8 Hello Everybody this it´s one test --- > BAD RESULT

**When the right order it´s the first without [ ]**

Hello everybody 1-2-3 this it´s one test 4-5-6-7-8

**The script i create :**

```
<?php

$text = " This is a test [gal~ruta~100~100] This is other test [gal~ruta2~100~100]";

function gal($matches)
{

global $text;

$exp=explode("~",$matches[1]);

$end=str_replace($matches[1],$a,$text);

if ($exp[0]=="gal")
{
$a="".$exp[1]."".$exp[2]."".$exp[3]."";
echo $a;
}


}


echo preg_replace_callback(
"/\[(.*?)\]/",
"gal",
$text);

?>
```

Thank´s everybody for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something from your callback, which will be substituted in the original string. You most certainly don't want to `echo`, which will send the values straight to the output, in order of execution.

However, it sounds like you don't even need a callback function to remove the brackets around your numbers.

```
$str = preg_replace("/\[(.*?)\]/", "$1", $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nfB7N9).

Comment: Yes right in the original string i use shortcodes and need replace this shortcodes for function which read gallery and show it , but i don´t get works and show the original string and replace these shortcodes for the function of gallery , Thank´s !!!

Comment: Yes right but these tags work as shortcode and need replace by function and in each case show gallery , and i can´t do this , i try many times and i can´t do works or if worls the order of text change ..... iif you need see all code i can put , thank´s